# Server side view in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, view, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET 5.0 project, if i add new cshtml view(from server side templates),  will it mean that the Javascript and CSS etc in that view will also be executed on server instead of client's browser? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript and CSS aren't executed on the server.  It's not really clear what you're asking.  *Having* a view doesn't increase any runtime load on the system.  Requests have to come in to *execute* the action/view in order to actually have a runtime effect.  An increased number of users can affect load, or heavy server-side code processing can affect load.  But just adding a view doesn't, nor does it have anything to do with JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: @David Then why it is called server side? and the c# which we write after @ sign is executed on server or client? If it is executed in server, will it lead to performance degradation?

Comment: Why is *what* "called server-side"?  The JavaScript?  It isn't.  Maybe you can demonstrate what you're talking about in the question?  C# is executed on the server, yes.  But C# isn't JavaScript or CSS.  And anything you execute on any system *technically* "leads to performance degradation" because doing something is more costly than not doing something.  But it's still not clear what you're actually asking here.  Will running code use more server resources than not running code?  Yes, yes it will.  Will it be noticeable?  Depends on the code and how often you run it.

Comment: @David I want all the code in view to be executed on client side, but when i try to add the cshtml view, its available only in server side templates. Its not about running vs not running. Its about running on client's browser vs running on server.

Comment: Regardless of what you may want, server-side code is executed on the server.  Browsers have no knowledge of C#.  Nor would they have any way of interacting with other server-side resources when executing that code.  Server-side code runs server-side, and client-side code runs client-side.  You seem to have some fundamental misconceptions regarding web development, which is probably where your confusion is coming from.

Comment: @David i have re phrased it. Hope it is clear now. And there is an HTML attribute asp-controller="abc". How will browser know where to execute it?

Comment: The answer to your question is simply: "No.  JavaScript and CSS will not be executed on the server."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only the C# razor code will be executed on the server. CSS will be rendered by the browser, and JavaScript code will also be executed by the browser. If you have code you want to run on the server, you must use razor. If you want it to run in the browser, use JavaScript. The cshtml extension simply tells the server to look for C# razor code to execute.

Comment: If i add 2 views, one client side and server side and write exactly same HTML code in both(no c#), will there be a performance difference wrt to server?

Comment: Everything starts off on the server and is passed to the client when requested. When the client requests a view, the server will parse the .cshtml file for razor code, run the code, then pass the result to the client. If there's no C# code, it will simply pass everything to the client. If you simply put a .html file in the wwwroot folder and the client requests that, the server will give it straight to the client without parsing. This might be a tiny bit faster, since it doesn't have to parse first, but the difference will be negligible.